# Error trying to get my first Rails application running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a book called "Learning Ruby" and under the section for rails is gives a step-by-step walk through of creating a simple Rails web app.

It says near the end type the command:

> ./script/generate scaffold addressbook addressbook

But part-way through I get the error:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

I assume this is because a slight version difference, but I cant get my rails application to work, and was hoping somebody here might be able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `script/generate scaffold` without any arguments, it will tell you how to use it:

```
$ script/generate scaffold
Usage: script/generate scaffold ModelName [field:type, field:type]

Options:
        --skip-timestamps            Don't add timestamps to the migration file for this model
        --skip-migration             Don't generate a migration file for this model
        --force-plural               Forces the generation of a plural ModelName

Rails Info:
    -v, --version                    Show the Rails version number and quit.
    -h, --help                       Show this help message and quit.

General Options:
    -p, --pretend                    Run but do not make any changes.
    -f, --force                      Overwrite files that already exist.
    -s, --skip                       Skip files that already exist.
    -q, --quiet                      Suppress normal output.
    -t, --backtrace                  Debugging: show backtrace on errors.
    -c, --svn                        Modify files with subversion. (Note: svn must be in path)
    -g, --git                        Modify files with git. (Note: git must be in path)

Description:
    Scaffolds an entire resource, from model and migration to controller and
    views, along with a full test suite. The resource is ready to use as a
    starting point for your RESTful, resource-oriented application.

    Pass the name of the model (in singular form), either CamelCased or
    under_scored, as the first argument, and an optional list of attribute
    pairs.

    Attribute pairs are column_name:sql_type arguments specifying the
    model's attributes. Timestamps are added by default, so you don't have to
    specify them by hand as 'created_at:datetime updated_at:datetime'.

    You don't have to think up every attribute up front, but it helps to
    sketch out a few so you can start working with the resource immediately.

    For example, 'scaffold post title:string body:text published:boolean'
    gives you a model with those three attributes, a controller that handles
    the create/show/update/destroy, forms to create and edit your posts, and
    an index that lists them all, as well as a map.resources :posts
    declaration in config/routes.rb.

    If you want to remove all the generated files, run
    'script/destroy scaffold ModelName'.

Examples:
    `./script/generate scaffold post`
    `./script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text published:boolean`
    `./script/generate scaffold purchase order_id:integer amount:decimal`
```